# canvas через javascript получить css background-color

Tags: css, html5, canvas, background

В стиле задан фон канваса: `#mainCanvas {  background-color:green; }`

Пытаюсь получить этот параметр, но значение пустое.

```
zoomCtx.fillStyle = mainCanvas.style.background;
```

Как исправить?

Comment: document.getElementById('mainCanvas')[0].style.backgroundColor http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp

Comment: @Jean-Claude
Спасибо. не работает. Возвращает пустое значение. А для чего [0] ?

Comment: пардон getElementById возвращает один элемент, остальные вроде getElementsByTagName- массив, поэтому там нужен индекс массива [0]. [рабочий пример](http://jsbin.com/kodivikimo/edit?html,css,js,output) тут. Как [получать стили](http://automated-testing.info/t/poluchenie-svojstv-css-elementa-iz-javascript/3795) написано тут.

Comment: @Jean-Claude
СпасиБо! Работает! 
`var bgc = getComputedStyle(mainCanvas).backgroundColor;`
(отмечу, как принятый, если как ответ это разместите..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementById возвращает один элемент, остальные, например, getElementsByTagName - массив, поэтому там нужен индекс массива [0]. Рабочий пример ниже.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('myid')).backgroundColor);
  console.log(getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0]).backgroundColor);
};
```

```css
div {
  background-color: tomato;
}
span {
  background-color: #bfa;
}
```

```html
<div id='myid'>div</div>
<span>span</span>
```

**Как получать стили** [написано](http://automated-testing.info/t/poluchenie-svojstv-css-elementa-iz-javascript/3795) тут.

Иногда нужно поработать с DOM в консоли браузера, в том числе получить значение стиля. Обычно это делается так:

```
element = document.getElementById('foo');
color = element.style.backgroundColor;
```

Но работает это только тогда, когда у элемента стиль задан inline:

```
<div style="color:red;">
```

Если же стиль задан в CSS, то element.style.backgroundColor ничего не вернёт.
Чтобы всё заработало, нужно запросить просчитанные стили:

```
element = document.getElementById('foo');
color = window.getComputedStyle(element).backgroundColor;
```